# Mysql record based on Multiple where clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in that common column is m_id based on that i have to select customer detail with maximum date_time  Let's call this table as customer:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| m_id | cus_id | se_id |
+------+--------+-------+
|    5 | 2      | 12    |
|    7 | 2      | 12    |
|    9 | 3      | 13    |
|    8 | 2      | 12    |
+------+--------+-------+
```

And this is table cus_detail:

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| m_id    | taxonomy | date_time          |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
|       5 | es       |2015-09-16 11:46:53 |
|       5 | es1      |2015-09-16 11:47:40 |
|       7 | es2      |2015-09-16 11:49:46 |
|       7 | es2      |2015-09-16 12:20:31 |
|       8 | es3      |2015-09-23 07:01:21 |
|       8 | es3      |2015-09-23 07:02:21 |
|       9 | es4      |2015-09-23 07:03:17 |
|       4 | es5      |2015-09-23 07:50:29 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

I have two input from our customer that is cus_id and se_id based on that i have to select m_id and customer details with maximum date_time value if cus_id=2 and se_id=12 means first pass it to the first table and get m_id and pass that m_id to second table where date_time also maximum i am expecting the following result

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| m_id    | taxonomy | date_time          |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
|       5 | es1      |2015-09-16 11:47:40 |
|       7 | es2      |2015-09-16 12:20:31 |
|       8 | es3      |2015-09-23 07:02:21 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

i am tried the following Mysql query but not get it the answer

```
SELECT * FROM `cus_detail` WHERE m_id in (SELECT m_id from customer where cus_id=2 and se_id=12) and date_time=(select max(date_time) from cus_detail)
```

please guide me to get correct result and i think left join will help me but unable to get it

Comment: Write the answer that you want and the answer that get what have you tried

Comment: i am not getting any output and i am mentioned the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `cus_detail` 
WHERE m_id in (SELECT m_id from customer where cus_id=2 and se_id=12) 
and date_time=(select max(date_time) from cus_detail)
```

The `date_time` selection is missing a key `m_id` to determine the correct `max(date_time)`:

```
SELECT * FROM cus_detail cd
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.m_id=cd.m_id AND c.cus_id=2 and c.se_id=12
INNER JOIN (select max(date_time) date_time,m_id from cus_detail GROUP BY m_id) cd2 
 ON cd.m_id=cd2.m_id and cd.date_time=cd2.date_time;
```